# Find the mean and standard deviation for the number of defective bulbs.

Tags: probability, statistics

From past, a company knows that in cartons of bulbs, 90% contain no defective bulbs, 5%
contain one defective bulb, 3% contain two defective bulbs, and 2% contain three defective
bulbs. Find the mean and standard deviation for the number of defective bulbs.

Comment: What goes wrong when you try to apply the usual formulas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you have the following distribution: $P(X=0)=0.9, P(X=1)=0.05, P(X=2)=0.03, P(X=3)=0.02$. From this you can derive both $\mathbf{E}X$ and $\mathbf{Var}X$.